# Troubleshooting python startup execution of a .sh file on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-scraping

My goal is to launch a script when an Ubuntu machine starts up.  The script kicks off some scrapers, and none of it appears to run on startup.  Looking through the forums, I've tried the applicable the recommended approaches, but perhaps I'm missing a step.

I want this script to run on startup:

```
#!/bin/sh
conda activate scraper
cd /home/me_user/Documents/scrape
python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py 2010 > /tmp/images2010.log &
python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py 2011 > /tmp/images2011.log &
python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py 2012 > /tmp/images2012.log &
python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py 2013 > /tmp/images2013.log &
python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py 2014 > /tmp/images2014.log &
python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py 2015 > /tmp/images2015.log &
```

When I run it myself from the command line from a local directory, it starts without issue and all of the python scripts kick off.

That looks like this when I run a copy of it:

```
. /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/init/launch_prod_images.sh
```

I wanted it to execute on startup, so I logged in as sudo, copied it to `/etc/init.d/` and did the following

```
chmod 777 /etc/init.d/launch_prod_images.sh
```

(initially, I did `chmod +x` on the file, but resorted to opening it all the way up with `chmod 777`.)

Then, created a symbolic link to

```
ln -s /etc/init.d/launch_prod_images.sh /etc/rc2.d/
```

When, I log into the machine, I'd expect to see those scripts running in the Task Manager window, but they aren't. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: usually Task Manager displays only your processes but this proces may belong to `root` or `system` and you may have to change setting to see all processes.

Comment: BTW: you can use `@reboot` in `cron` to run some code at start.

Comment: Thanks @furas, I ended up settling on cron to do what I want for now.

Answer (score 1):

As @furas suggested, `cron` is the way to go for now and one cron job for each.

Some important changes which helped:

1. The correct permissions are set for all of the files being called through execution.
2. Just do the `cd` within crontab
3. Explicit path to python

```
@reboot cd /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/ && /opt/anaconda3/envs/scraper/bin/python /home/me_user/Documents/scrape/prod_images.py >> /tmp/images2010.log
```